# Insert and Update data in database at the same time

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

**What i want**- i want to insert data into database if no existing data, and update if the data already exist in database.

**Problem** - If i click submit button without enter new data, the data still insert into database.

This is my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<?php 
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("cuba");


    if(isset($_POST['hantar']))
    {

        for($a=1; $a<=count($_POST['name']); $a++)
        {

            /*$sqlQuery = "REPLACE INTO a (id,name,ic) VALUES     ('".$_POST['id'][$a]."','".$_POST['name'][$a]."', '".$_POST['ic'][$a]."')";   */
            $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO a (id,name,ic) VALUES     ('".$_POST['id'][$a]."','".$_POST['name'][$a]."', '".$_POST['ic'][$a]."' ) on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='".$_POST['name'][$a]."', ic ='".$_POST['ic'][$a]."'";   
            mysql_query($sqlQuery)or die(mysql_error());

        }

    }
    ?>
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="b">
   <?php


    $a = 1;
    $share = mysql_query("select *from a")or die(mysql_error());
    while($share_papar = mysql_fetch_array($share))
    {
    ?>
            <table class="bb" style="border:1px solid #003;">
                <tr>
                    <td width="200">Name</td>
                    <td> : <input type="text" class="input_teks" name="name[]" value="<?    php echo $share_papar['name'];?>" />

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>ic</td>
                    <td> : <input type="text" class="input_teks" name="ic[]" value="<?php echo $share_papar['ic'];?>" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>id</td>
                    <td> : <input type="text" class="input_teks" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $share_papar['id'];?>" id="akhir"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="right" class="b_buang">Remove</td>


                </tr>
            </table>
        <?php 
    }?>    
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="ss" name="hantar">
            </form>
            <span class="b_tambah">Add new group</span>

         <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function()
        {


            //nk clone
            $('.b_tambah').on('click',function(e)
            {

                 $(".b").find(".bb").last().clone(true).appendTo(".b");
                 alert(     $(".bb:last").find("input[id=akhir]").last().val());
                var m =      $(".bb:last").find("input[id=akhir]").last();
                m.val("");
            });

            //nk buang
             $(".b_buang").click(function () {

                    if($('.bb').length < 2)
                     {
                            alert("Remove operation can be done if GROUP more than one"); 
                     }
                    else
                    {
                        $(this).parents(".bb").remove();
                    }
            });

        });
        </script>
    <!-- close clone Shareholders -->

    </td>
```

I'm using jquery to clone form same with update form, then reset value to blank for input type name (id), so i can have non match id with existing data. But if i submit form without cloning those form, the data will insert into database. What i want is, no need to insert data into database if i dont cloning the new data and just update the existing. How i can achieve that..

Comment: Please use `MYSQLI` instead `msql` to prevent sql injection

Comment: Why do u use HyperText preprocessor? Are you poor ?go for rich language ASP.net

Comment: why can't you check if name is not null or empty before insert on server?

Comment: @Pratik Joshi- i'm just helping my friends

Comment: @Sunny-how can i check it because i not add it with the new data..

Comment: echo "INSERT INTO a (id,name,ic) VALUES     ('".$_POST['id'][$a]."','".$_POST['name'][$a]."', '".$_POST['ic'][$a]."' ) on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='".$_POST['name'][$a]."', ic ='".$_POST['ic'][$a]."'"; What you see, post here.

Comment: @RohitAwasthi - the new blank data insert into database.

Comment: No, put this echo and see what string it shows on screen.

Comment: here.. INSERT INTO a (id,name,ic) VALUES ('28','koo2', '21' ) on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='koo2', ic ='21'INSERT INTO a (id,name,ic) VALUES ('','', '' ) on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='',

Comment: thats it...INSERT INTO a (id,name,ic) VALUES ('','', '' ) on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='',  this is the problem. Put validations so as to not to insert empty values

Comment: i tried to make if($_POST['name'][$a]==""){do nothing}else{do something} but the data still insert into db..

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
if(isset($_POST['hantar']))
    {

        for($a=1; $a<=count($_POST['name']); $a++)
        {

            $name = $_POST['name'][$a];
            $ic = $_POST['ic'][$a];
            $name = $_POST['name'][$a];

            $sel = mysql_query("select * from a where name = '$name' and ic = '$ic'  ");

            if(mysql_num_rows($sel) > 0){ 
            //write  update query   
            $fet  =mysql_fetch_array($sel); 
            $auto_increment_id = $fet['id']; 
             $sqlQuery = " update a set name = '$name' , ic = '$ic' where id = '$auto_increment_id' "; 
            }
            else { 
            // write insert query 
             $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO a (id,name,ic) VALUES     ('".$_POST['id'][$a]."','".$_POST['name'][$a]."', '".$_POST['ic'][$a]."' ) ";   


            }
             mysql_query($sqlQuery)or die(mysql_error());

        }

    }
```

Comment: duplicate entry primary key

Answer (score 0):

first check the `$_POST['name']` in `SELECT` query if it is exsits update in the query if not then insert into database

Comment: if i dont add new data(cloning from update form), this code will insert blank data for all fields except for id

Comment: why you are inserting id. Why you not making id an autoincrement?

Comment: i already make it as you said. if i dont inserting id, the existing data never update..

Comment: if you make an id autoincrement it will never inserted. Query always show an error. Check your table

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

```
for($a=1; $a<=count($_POST['name']); $a++)
```

to

```
for($a=0; $a < count($_POST['name']); $a++)
```

And also check validation
e.g.

```
if(isset($_POST['name'][$a]) && trim($_POST['name'][$a]) != "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally.. This code save me..

```
if(isset($_POST['hantar']))
    {

        for($a=0; $a < count($_POST['name']); $a++)
        {
            if($_POST['name'][$a]=="")
            {

            }else
            {

            if($_POST['id'][$a]=="")
            {
                $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO a (name,ic) VALUES ('".$_POST['name'][$a]."', '".$_POST['ic'][$a]."' )";   
                mysql_query($sqlQuery)or die(mysql_error());
            }
            else
            {
            $sqlQuery = " update a set name = '{$_POST['name'][$a]}' , ic = '{$_POST['ic'][$a]}' where id = '{$_POST['id'][$a]}' "; 
            mysql_query($sqlQuery)or die(mysql_error());
            }

            }
        }

    }
```